# DispatcherServlet doesn't redirect to the appropriate view

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml

I keep getting the **404 not found** HTTP response when asking for the appropriate view.

These are my config files.

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
             id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

        <display-name>ssytem-ecommerce-prototype-view</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:appContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

**mvc-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <annotation-driven></annotation-driven>
        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan base-package="ma.pack.net.*"></context:component-scan>

        <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        </beans:bean>

    </beans:beans>
```

**HomeController.java**

```
    package ma.pack.net;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home() {
            return "entry";
        }
    }
```

**entry.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Hello, This is the Front Page</b>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't know where i made the mistake, i tried to change the name of mappings of controller, page names, page extension but i keep getting the same output.

Comment: Is the entry.html file inside /WEB-INF/view/ directory? Do you have logging enabled and if so can you provide the log ? Are you sure the application is being deployed without any problems? What is the name of your war file and what is the address you are accessing in your browser?

Comment: war-file-name: **ssytem-ecommerce-prototype-view-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war**, i confirm that it's inside WEB-INF/view/ directory. The address looks like this **http://localhost:8080/ssytem-ecommerce-prototype-view/**

Comment: **InternalViewResolver** should do the mapping after the **DispatcherServlet** makes the correct mapping between the request and the appropriate controller which is in this case **HomeController**

Comment: I don't know what do you mean exactly by another servlet, based on my understanding, the dispatcher will pick the **HomeController** and will give the name of the view to **InternalViewResolver** to update with the prefix and suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by making some modifications on some configuration files.

As long as i wanna manipulate html not jsp files, it means we're looking for static content, so all i had to do is to change my **mvc-config.xml** file to this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <annotation-driven></annotation-driven>
        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan base-package="ma.pack.net"></context:component-scan>

        <resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/"></resources>


    </beans:beans>
```

I also changed my **HomeController.java**  class to the following

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home() {
            return "static/entry.html";
        }
    }
```

Now the **ViewResolver** has no interference in order to generate the appropriate view.

Answer (score 2):

## Falling Back On the "Default" Servlet To Serve Resources

This allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "`/`" (thus overriding the mapping of the container’s default Servlet), while still allowing static resource requests to be handled by the container’s default Servlet. It configures a `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` with a URL mapping of "`/**`" and the lowest priority relative to other URL mappings.

This handler will forward all requests to the default Servlet. Therefore it is important that it remains last in the order of all other URL HandlerMappings. That will be the case if you use `<mvc:annotation-driven>`; if you are setting up your own customized HandlerMapping instance, the be sure to set its order property to a value lower than that of the DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler, which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

To enable the feature using the default setup use:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Or in XML:

```xml
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

The caveat to overriding the "`/`" Servlet mapping is that the RequestDispatcher for the default Servlet must be retrieved by name rather than by path. The DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler will attempt to auto-detect the default Servlet for the container at startup time, using a list of known names for most of the major Servlet containers (including Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish, JBoss, Resin, WebLogic, and WebSphere). If the default Servlet has been custom configured with a different name, or if a different Servlet container is being used where the default Servlet name is unknown, then the default Servlet’s name must be explicitly provided as in the following example:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable("myCustomDefaultServlet");
    }

}
```

Or in XML:

```xml
<mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="myCustomDefaultServlet"/>
```

### Your `mvc-config.xml`:

```xml
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

Comment: Thanks. <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> was the key.